# GSON deserialization behaviour

Tags: gson, deserialization

I am deserializing a JSON payload to a POJO and in the POJO I have a HashMap (userIdMap) that is declared & initialized as follows:

```
public class ObjectProvider {

    private String companyId;

    @Expose(serialize = true, deserialize = true)
    @SerializedName("entity_id")
    private String entityId;

    @Expose(serialize = true, deserialize = true)
    @SerializedName("url")
    private String url;


    private String responseTemplate;

    private Map<String, String> userIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    ...// REST OF CODE REMOVED FOR READABILITY

}
```

However after the POJO is created when I try to access the userIdMap attribute to perform a GET operation I get java.lang.NullPointerException. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong ?

Comment: The issue has been solved. Looks like the default constructor was missing in the class. Once I add the default constructor and initialize the Map it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved. Looks like the default constructor was missing in the class. Once I add the default constructor and initialize the Map it works fine.